# Нет выбора, ОС Ubuntu и Windows 10

Tags: windows, ubuntu, dual-boot

Стояла Win 7 и Ubuntu при перезагрузке мог выбрать какую грузить ОС. Решил вместо 7 поставить 10. Установил на диск где стояла 7. При перезагрузке грузит только 10 без выбора ОС, хотя еще пишет можно 7 выбрать но при выборе начинается процесс востановления, но я думаю, что это не то. Что делать? Как вернуть выбор Ubuntu и Windows 10?

Comment: Советую live cd убунты взять. И ещё раз граб накатить. Всегда советуют сначала Винду ставить, потом линукс но не наоборот.

Comment: А зачем Вам винда? или наоборот линух? Оставьте что-нибудь одно и не парьтесь. Если пристрастились к компьютерным играм или фотожопу какому, то линух можно и в виртуалке запускать время от времени, если нападет такая блаж

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При любой установке/переустановке Выни, она в наглую затирает все загрузчики, отличные от выневского!!!..  Поэтому после установки/переустановки Выни, нужно заново установить Grub!

Раз у вас стоит 10 Win, то это можно сделать средствами самой win 10:

- запускаете cmd от имени администратора
- вводите в терминале `>bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`
- Презагружаетесь.

> PS команда стработает, если у вас стоит UEFI !!!